# How to pass complex objects via SignalR in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-5, signalr-hub

My working SignalR ASP.NET Core 5 Windows Service with a simple **string** payload (or even more value type parameters) does not work anymore when I change it to a (simple) complex object ("CommonMessage" in my case). From what I read, it should work out of the box. The "SendCommonMessage" method doesn't get called anymore and I am not getting any error. What am I missing? Is there no way of debugging/getting the error shown? (The ASP.NET Service gets called by a WPF Core 5 application.)

```
public class CommonMessageHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendCommonMessage(CommonMessage commonMessage)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveCommonMessage", commonMessage);
    }
}

public class CommonMessage
{
    public int MessageType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The caller (WPF app) looks like so:

```
public class CommonMessageService
{
    public CommonMessageService(HubConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _connection.On<CommonMessage>("ReceiveCommonMessage", commonMessage => CommonMessageReceived?.Invoke(commonMessage));
    }

    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public event Action<CommonMessage> CommonMessageReceived;

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        await _connection.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task SendCommonMessage(CommonMessage commonMessage)
    {
        await _connection.SendAsync("SendCommonMessage", commonMessage);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you actually consuming the `CommonMessageReceived` event? How are you registering `ICommonMessageService`?

Comment: @Andy: The event is consumed in a ViewModel and the interface is currently not needed, I removed it. I implemented an exact 1:1 copy which uses a string, and it works. The problem must be the complex object "CommonMessage". The SendCommonMessage() method in the WPF app gets called but the call doesn't reach the SendCommonMessage() in the service.

Comment: Do you have any indication of an error in the logs?

Comment: @Ihusaan: In which logs? I added the service log, if that is what you mean. Only the "test" hub (with a string payload) is working properly, the other two are not working.